# redirect problems with authorization in strava.com using scrapy. Log says that strava redirects me from /login to /login

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I really need your help: tried already everything! The goal - authorize the https://www.strava.com/login using scrapy

That's my code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser


class StravaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'strava'
    start_urls = ('https://www.strava.com/dashboard',)

    def parse(self, response):
        token = response.xpath('//*[@name="csrf-token"]/@content').get()
        return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                         formdata={
                                             'authenticity_token': token,
                                             'plan': "",
                                             'email': 'login',
                                             'password': 'password'},
                                         #dont_filter=True,
                                         #meta={'dont_redirect': True, 'handle_httpstatus_list': [302]},
                                         callback=self.scrape_page)

    def scrape_page(self, response):
        print('okkkk', '\n\n\n\n')
        open_in_browser(response)
```

The problem is in redirecting:

```
2020-08-16 20:18:49 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.strava.com/dashboard> from <POST https://www.strava.com/session>
2020-08-16 20:18:49 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Assigned User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.79 Safari/537.36
2020-08-16 20:18:49 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.strava.com/login> from <GET https://www.strava.com/dashboard>
2020-08-16 20:18:49 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Assigned User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36
2020-08-16 20:18:50 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.strava.com/dashboard> from <GET https://www.strava.com/login>
2020-08-16 20:18:50 [scrapy.dupefilters] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET https://www.strava.com/dashboard> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
2020-08-16 20:18:50 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

I turned off duplicate filter, added handle_httpstatus_list, added scrapy-redirect in settings....nothing works.
Please no bs4 or selenium - I've already did this program with them, now I need only scrapy and this authorization...makes me cry

Comment: The Form data in Request Headers of post request is utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=W28zQ9XWLK7oktgDzUj0kCozODXk2bJQLAqPihwEJ8gwj1VDKtA7c5AWwTw0OUovnyAZkcXiNdF2Zt4AsNOIUQ%3D%3D&plan=&email=&password=

Comment: **What exactly is the problem?** Is the redirecting infinite? What happened when you used `don't_filter=True`. I don't think that you provided enough information for us to help you. **On a wild guess**, I suggest you executing your spider with the following command: `scrapy crawl strava -s COOKIES_ENABLED=True` and see if it helps.

Comment: If I do `dont_filter=True` it returns me https://www.strava.com/login. cookies_enabled didn't help((

Comment: @renatodvc And  if I make a mistake in a password or login - it really goes to callback function and returns me a page with 'The username or password did not match. Please try again.'       It means that my authorization works, but scrapy doesn't follow strava redirection

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me.

Comment: @gangabass ,has he opened https://www.strava.com/dashboard page?

Comment: @Michael not a dashboard but this page: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p586lfejaoi0qkn/Strava.htm?dl=0

Comment: @gangabass how you took html of this page? Ye, it's cool that smth happens, but I need to move to dashboard